# How to convert and compare a date string to a date in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
= "7/29/2011 12:58:00 PM" > NOW()
```

I'd like this expression to return FALSE and yet it returns TRUE.

I know I can break apart my datetime into a date and a time and add them together as follows:

```
= DateValue("7/29/2011") + TimeValue("12:58:00 PM") > NOW()
```

But, this seems inelegant to me. I want a simple function or approach that looks nice and I feel certain that it's out there but I just can't find it.

I also know there is a VBA function called `CDate` which can typecast the string into a datetime and that would be perfect. But, I don't see how to call a VBA function in an excel cell.

Comment: Are your date strings "hard-coded" in the cells like that? If so, why?

Comment: They are. Is there another format to type them that's better?

Comment: Well, why isn't `7/29/2011 12:58:00 PM` in a cell on its own whose format is set to Date? Hard-coding the string like that makes it pretty invisible and inflexible.

Comment: Ah. So that's the best practice. I'm going to do that. But, in some cases the formula needs to have it so I'll just accept what I thought was the simplest answer which is at the moment the *1. Thanks to you as well.

Comment: Yes, I think that's good practice, while your example looks like terrible practice! Why would anyone ever want to do that?! See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm upgrading the following from a comment to an answer:

Unless you have a very specific reason to do so (and right now I can't think of any), dates (and other values) really shouldn't be "hard-coded" in cells as strings like you show. Hard-coding the string like that makes it invisible and inflexible. The user will just see `TRUE` or `FALSE` with no indication of what this means.

I would just put your date `7/29/2011 12:58:00 PM` in a cell on its own e.g. A1, and set the cell's format to some date format. Then you can say `= A1 > NOW()`.

Contrary to @jonsca's and @Tiago Cardoso's answers, this answer doesn't address your specific question, but then again, what you are asking seems like really bad practice to me!

Answer (score 8):

Multiply the string by one and the comparison function will work:

```
= 1*"7/29/2011 12:58:00 PM" > NOW()
```

The answer to your question is tightly related to @Jean-François's comment: Why is the date being interpreted by Excel as a Text and not by a date?

Once you find it out, you'll be able to do the comparison.

If that's because the string is being retrieved as a text, you can simply multiply it by one and the comparison function will work, then. But it applies only in case the string format is a valid date/time format in your regional settings.

Comment: this is great. gotta give you +1. but in the end gonna isolate the date.

Comment: Main point of this answer (*multiply it by one and the comparison function will work*) should be placed front and center, not buried in the middle of the third paragraph! Allowing myself to do this. This hack is good to know. +1

Comment: Yes. For Excel short  & pretty solutions are welcome. If someday Excel becomes a nice tool, I hope it will be retro-compatible

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap the VBA call in a custom function:

```
Function ReturnDate(ByVal datestr As String) As Date
    ReturnDate = CDate(datestr)
End Function
```

which you can use just like a formula in your sheet.

Comment: I can't think of a way to just call the `CDate` directly from the formula, but such a way may exist.

Comment: i will accept this if someone doesn't come up with a better answer. this seems like a work around although it is a nice workaround.

Comment: Addressing the X of an XY problem can be so painful! +1

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to make a VBA function that uses CDATE and return your comparison. Then, call the function from an excel cell.

The VBA Function

```
Public Function compareDate(ByVal inputDate As String) As Boolean
  compareDate = CDate(inputDate) > Now()
End Function
```

Then in your spreadsheet, just do

```
=compareDate("YOUR DATE")
```

The function will return "FALSE" if it is older and "TRUE" if it is newer than Now()

Comment: Same as @jonsca's answer save cosmetics